# Golang reflection on interface vs pointer-to-interface

Tags: go

In the example of gob usage http://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/example_interface_test.go they provide the following thesis:
`Pass pointer to interface so Encode sees (and hence sends) a value of interface type.  If we passed p directly it would see the concrete type instead. See the blog post, "The Laws of Reflection" for background.`

I've read The Laws of reflection twice, and a related Russ Cox article too. But I can't find a distinction between pointer-to-interface and interface there.

So why is it that through the pointer it sees a value of interface type, and with no pointer it sees (surprisingly to me) the concrete type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the relevant part is [this](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.):

> Continuing, we can do this:
>
> ```
> var empty interface{}
> empty = w
> ```
>
> **and our empty interface value empty will again contain that same pair, (tty, *os.File).** That's handy: an empty interface can hold any value and contains all the information we could ever need about that value.

*(emphasis added)*

When you assign an interface value to a value of type `interface{}`, the "pointer to data" part of the new value doesn't point to the old value, but rather to the data old value was pointing to. We can prove that with a bit of `unsafe` code:

```
type iface struct {
    Type, Data unsafe.Pointer
}

var r io.Reader = &bytes.Buffer{}
var i interface{} = r

rr := *(*iface)(unsafe.Pointer(&r))
ii := *(*iface)(unsafe.Pointer(&i))

fmt.Printf("%v\n", ii.Data == rr.Data) // Prints true.
```

On the other hand, if we use a pointer, it *will* point to the interface value itself. So now `reflect` can actually see, what interface exactly are we talking about. E.g.:

```
var i2 interface{} = &r
ii2 := *(*iface)(unsafe.Pointer(&i2))
fmt.Printf("%v\n", ii2.Data == unsafe.Pointer(&r)) // Prints true.
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/0ZEMdIFhIj

Comment: Thank for pointing the direction and providing with useful example.